# How to change the "cancel(erase)" X icon in the Guide Search input field with another one from my imported library

Tags: html, input, icons, native, shadow-dom

I want the browser's native cancel icon inside the input(type="search") to be placed with my custom icon from an imported library.

it is clear that we can use that CSS to hide the browser native icon and replace it with another image, but my issue here is the icon that I wanted it to be placed is an icon imported from a library @custom-icons.

```
`#input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 content: URL();
 cursor: pointer;
  }`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.